# Does Inspiring Presence affect Threatening Shout - Demoralize

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

Does `Inspiring Presence` increase the taunt time of `Threatening Shout - Demoralize` from 4 seconds to 8 seconds?

Comment: If you down vote, leave a comment explaining "why". Otherwise, your vote does nothing to help improve the question.

Comment: Comments for downvotes are not necessary, and asking for them tends to not go over well.  The system works as intended.

Comment: "The system works as intended." So, the system is intended to encourage questions to never get improved? That is strange. I thought the system was there to help improve the quality of questions with constructive feedback.

Comment: No, the system is designed to seperate good questions and answers from bad.  Helping people is usually just a happy bonus.  I'd recommend updating your question to include more details about this, rather than just your straight question.  That would help readers figure out what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: What other details do you need? The question seems very clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this today @ version 2.0.4.23119 on live servers.

[Here is a video showing the test and results.](http://youtu.be/gUH6DPMROzs)

My conclusion is that Inspiring Presence does not increase the taunt time of Threatening Shout - Demoralize.